# Shortest acyclic path on directed cyclic graph with negative weights/cycles

Tags: graph, shortest-path

I have a directed graph which has cycles.
All edges are weighted, and the weights can be negative.
There can be negative cycles.

I want to find a path from s to t, which minimizes the total weight on the path.
Sure, it can go to negative infinity when negative cycles exist.
But what if I disallow cycles in the path (not in the original graph)?
That is, once the path leaves a node, it can not enter the node again.

This surely avoids the negative infinity problem,
but surprisingly no known algorithm is found by a search on Google.
The closest is Floyd–Warshall algorithm, but it does not allow negative cycles.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit: I may have generalized my original problem too much. Indeed, I am given a cyclic directed graph with nonnegative edge weights. But in addition, each node has a positive reward too. I want to find a simple path which minimizes (sum of edge weights on the path) - (sum of node rewards covered by the path). This can be surely converted to the question that I posted, but some structure is lost. And some hint from submodular analysis suggests this motivating problem is not NP-hard. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will copy my answer from [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17462) on the CS-theory Stackexchange:

> Paths with no repeated vertices are called [simple-paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29#Different_types_of_paths), so you are looking for the shortest simple-path in a graph with negative-cycles.
>
> This can be reduced from the [longest-path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).  If there were a fast solver for your problem, then given a graph with only positive edge-weights, negating all the edge-weights and running your solver would give the longest path in the original graph.
>
> Thus your problem is NP-Hard.

Comment: Oh, on the second thought, I may have generalized my original problem too much.  Indeed, I am given a cyclic directed graph with nonnegative edge weights.  But in addition, each node has a positive reward too.  I want to find a simple path which minimizes (sum of edge weights on the path) - (sum of node rewards covered by the path).  This can be surely converted to the question that I posted, but some structure is lost.  And some hint from submodular analysis suggests this motivating problem is not NP-hard.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Janathan: Your new question is essentially the same as [this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16226) *(which I also happened to answer :) )*.  However, in the future, rather than completely changing your question, please simply ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Danny.  I re-posted the question at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19483/shortest-simple-path-with-minimum-edge-cost-minus-node-reward